# Divide rows of a table in groups of 4 or more specific rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have two tables:

One with all the information on the Customers of my area, named [CFT1409](It has ~1 million rows); And the other has all the Customers that have Debts in the firm, named [Bcodebt](It has ~200 thousand rows).

Using this query:

> Select c.LocationCode, c.CustomerId, c.CustomerCode, c.Status, d.DebtDate From CFT1409 As c
> Left Join Bcodebt d On Convert(int, c.CustomerId)=Convert(int, d.CustomerId)
>
> Order by c.CustomerCode

```
LocationCode CustomerId CustomerCode             Status DebtDate 
------------ ---------- ------------------------ ------ -------- 
921          08086082   011100280142015500000001 A      201409
921          08086084   011100280142015500000002 I      201409
921          01646607   011100280142016000000000 A      NULL
921          01646608   011100280142017000000000 A      NULL
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      201212
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      201301
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      201303
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      201304
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      201302
921          01646610   011100280142018200000000 A      NULL
921          01646611   011100280142018500000001 A      201409
921          06226345   011100280142018500000002 A      201409
921          01646612   011100280142019500000000 A      201409
921          01646612   011100280142019500000000 A      201408
```

What I need to do is:

- Divide the results in groups of 4 or more sequencial (order by CustomerCode) **inactive (Status='I') customers.**
- Add a new column determining which customers of those groups have debts (I used the [DebtDate] columns to help this, so the 'Null' are the ones without debts).

So the results should be like this (only 4 or more sequencial inactives ('I') are in groups, the others can be ignored):

```
LocationCode CustomerId CustomerCode             Status DebtStatus DebtGroup
------------ ---------- ------------------------ ------ ---------- ---------
921          08086082   011100280142015500000001 A      1                   
921          08086084   011100280142015500000002 I      1                   
921          01646607   011100280142016000000000 A      0                   
921          01646608   011100280142017000000000 A      0                   
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      1          1        
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      1          1        
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      1          1        
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      1          1        
921          01646609   011100280142017500000000 I      1          1        
921          01646610   011100280142018200000000 A      0                   
921          01646611   011100280142018500000001 A      1                   
921          06226345   011100280142018500000002 I      1          2        
921          01646612   011100280142019500000000 I      1          2        
921          01646612   011100280142019500000000 I      1          2        
921          01646613   011100280142019500000001 I      0          2        
921          01646614   011100280142019500000002 A      0
```

Is there a way to do this on SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Why you are using SQL Server 2000? I am even not able to check in the MSDN if given functio nis suppoerted by SQL Server 2000 - the last record is for SQL Server 2005. If this is for homework or university you should upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for work, and this is the only version i have permission to work with.